# Can the onyomi be longer than 2 morae?

Tags: kanji

I started learning japanese recently, and I looked back at the kanji I've learned, and I simply can't think of any kanji with an onyomi longer than 2 morae.

Is there really no kanji with an onyomi longer than 2 morae, and if so, why?

Comment: 十【じゅう】、上【じょう】、食【しょく】……

Comment: @ZhenLin The yoons modify the kana to the left, so じゅ kind of acts like a single character.

Comment: In terms of just *kana*, @ZhenLin is right. If we're talking syllables (or mora), then no, there is no 3-syllable *kanji* *on*-reading (at least in the *jouyou* list).

Comment: I changed the question to ask about morae.

Comment: The kanji 褱 is supposedly read カイエ (in Mandarin, huai2), but this kanji is a 表外字, and I cannot find any words that use it. That said, if you were to find a kanji with three morae, I suspect it would probably be one that ends in two あ行 morae.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's actually カイ and エ separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that on-yomi are derived from the Chinese pronunciation of characters, which are (with [few exceptions](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3330)) monosyllabic. The basic structure of a syllable in [Middle Chinese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Chinese#Phonology) is as follows:

- An initial consonant
- A glide
- A vowel
- A final – either another glide or a consonant, but not both

For instance, 關 (resp. 怪, 脚) is *kwæn* (resp. *kwai*, *kjak*) in Middle Chinese and has the kan-on クヮン (resp. クヮイ, キャク), but there are no syllables like *kwain*. Thus there is no way a trimoraic on-yomi would arise.

Comment: What happened here? [米](http://jisho.org/search/%E7%B1%B3%20%23kanji) has an onyomi of メエトル

Comment: That's not on-yomi. It's obviously "metre", from French.

Comment: Sure, but why is it then listed under on?

Comment: Why don't you ask the person who created the website?